# Java Generate Unique Surrogate alphanumeric key based on text

Tags: java, security, md5, sha

I wanted to generate a unique key based on few columns(one of them is the search word....so the length can very long). The volume of records is around 6 million. I have used MD5 and generated a 32-character alphanumeric string. How confident can we be that this will be unique? Can you suggest any other solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). Let the database generate it for you.

Comment: Is there a Java question in here? Is there a security question in here (other than your choice of using a hash)?

Comment: If you are worried about uniqueness with 128-bit MD5 hashes or 160-bit SHA1, look at SHA2 (384 or 512 bits) for which no collisions have as yet been found.

Answer (score 0):

Find MD5 data of that MD5 what you have got earlier of that word.
eg.
Converting from String to MD5
"password"=>"5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99"
"5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99"=>"696d29e0940a4957748fe3fc9efd22a3"

For getting back you have to do this for two times
eg
"696d29e0940a4957748fe3fc9efd22a3"=>"5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
"5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99=>"password"

You may use this site for online testing 
http://md5.gromweb.com/

You may do this till you want.Hope this help you :)

Answer (score 0):

To really guarantee the uniqueness, you must check every new item agaist the whole history.

For instance, you can organize a table in RDB with primary key valued as your generated one and keep on generating until your insert actually succeeds. Sounds like a huge overhead but for most practical purposes it is not.

Another approach could be, again if a RDB is available and have a facility similar to sequence in Oracle, is to use this facility in conjunction with your algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your response...but RDB is not available. For our use case since the probability of a duplicate is very low, we can go forward as per business.